# About closure when using jQuery hover method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code:

```
function Demo (){
  this.name = 'abc';
  this.age = 20;
}

var demo = {
  init : function(){
    $('#test').hover(this.stop, this.start);
  },

  start: function(){
    //here is the error
    alert(this.name);
  }

  stop: function(){
    alert(this.age); // 'this' does not mean the Demo object, but $('#test') object.
  }
}

Demo.prototype = demo;
Demo.prototype.constructor = Demo;

(new Demo).init();
```

When the hover event of $('#test') is triggered, the stop method is called. However, 'this' in the method does not point to the demo object, but the $('#test') object. So, the alert is undefined. I need to have access to the attributes in the Demo object. And the stop and start method will be reused in other place, so I don not like to write the whole method code into hover's argument.
How should I solve this problem?

Comment: your not using a closure there. you have a an function based object and a JSON based object no part of that is a closure however why `(new Demo).init();` your think it should be `(new Demo()).init();` as Demo is a function that returns the object `Demo`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Refer to the main JavaScript object from functions which are methods on a subobject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763713/refer-to-the-main-javascript-object-from-functions-which-are-methods-on-a-subobj)

Comment: This question has been asked countless times here on SO, in one form or another. The canonical form of the question is "How do I pass an object method as a callback parameter to [setTimeout, $.ajax, Promise.then, $.on, etc. etc.]? Why doesn't it work to just pass `this.method`?" The basic reason is that whoever is calling you back doesn't know what `this` to invoke the callback with, so you have to "bind" the callback in one way or another. The question suggested as a duplicate is just one of many answers you'll find to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery uses [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) behind the scenes to call the event callbacks, that's why the context changes.

To mitigate this, you can do one of two things:

**Use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)**

```
var demo = {
  init : function(){
    $('#test').hover(this.stop.bind(this), this.start.bind(this));
  },

  start: function(){
    alert(this.name);
  }

  stop: function(){
    alert(this.age);
  }
}
```

**call the method directly**

```
var demo = {
  init : function(){
    // Closure here
    var self = this;
    $('#test').hover(function() {
        self.stop();
    }, function() {
        self.start();
    });
  },

  start: function(){
    alert(this.name);
  }

  stop: function(){
    alert(this.age);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `this` in the `start` and `stop` methods don't necessarily point to the same `this` as in the `init`.  This is because they are callback functions.  If you want to refer to the same object context then try the following:

```
var demo = {
  init : function(){
    $('#test').hover(this.stop.bind(this), this.start.bind(this));
  },

  start: function(){
    //here is the error
    alert(this.name);
  }

  stop: function(){
    alert(this.age); // 'this' does not mean the Demo object, but $('#test') object.
  }
}
```

Using `bind` will pass the `this` context through to the callbacks.
[MDN docs for bind are here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: You cant declare a variable in the middle of an object. The code is not correct

Comment: @MartinBarker I don't understand your comment.  Where is a JSON object in my answer?  Do you mean object literal?

Comment: `var demo = {}` that is JSON as it uses `key:value,` this is JSON

Comment: No, JSON has no methods.  this is called an object literal.

Comment: It is still JavaScript Object Notation it works with methods as function are still variable in Javascript here is an example i have run in the chrome inspector console. `var hello = "hello";
/*undefined*/
function hello(){ return "hello"; }
/*undefined*/
console.log(hello)
/*function hello(){ return "hello"; }
undefined*/` comments are the return values to the console you can try this your self

Comment: @MartinBarker JSON is an object notation, there is no JSON object

Comment: @A.Wolff you over complicated what i was saying im trying to say that it's using JSON to build an object for no reason it could all be done in the function `Demo` as that will return an object of Demo

Comment: @MartinBarker I still don't see anywhere a JSON notation in OP's code (nor in this answer), so what do you mean?  `var demo = {} that is JSON  as it uses key:value` No, it is not JSON

Comment: JSON code in JS is automaticly evaluated now! if you tried this in IE6 it would not work as JSON code is not automaticly evaluated, i know this as i used to have problems with it, the reason it works the way JS works as it does not go though the standard JSON parser it will just use it as Object Notation though its own JavaScript engine and as functions are variable in JS you it works though `key:value` just the value is not checked if it is a var is always set even if it is set to `undefined` it's sort of a planned exploit in the JS Engines realtime JSON Parsers

Comment: Thank you @DavinTryon , bind is the easiest way to make it work.

Comment: Just as a note @JasonW bind is not part of his original answer please make sure credit are given to NicoSantangelo for the bind method as that was in his answer before this one was updated with it :)

Answer (score -1):

A None JSON implementation that will allow you to set the variable self

```
function Demo(){
  this.name = 'abc';
  this.age = 20;
}

Demo.prototype = new (function(){
    var self = this;

    this.init = function(){
      $('#test').hover(self.stop, self.start);
    }

    this.start = function(){
      //here is the error
      alert(self.name);
    }

    this.stop = function(){
      alert(self.age); // 'this' does not mean the Demo object, but $('#test') object.
    }
  })();

(new Demo()).init()
```

EDIT:
I have updated to show what i was meaning without the use of `var demo = {...}` the point i was trying to make was not to use the `Object Literal` aka JSON style so you could support a variable inside the prototype

Comment: While this will work, it's not exactly the same as setting a prototype. And as @davin-tryon pointed out, the question is not a JSON implementation it's just an object literal

Comment: Thank you @MartinBarker , I will try your way later. it needs more changes of code than using bind().